# changing images rapidly in java android

Tags: java, android, image, onclicklistener

I am having a problem in changing images rapidly on click. I have made an image button I want to change the image when the button is clicked and back to the previous image. I have searched a lot but cant find the solution.

```
public class Buttonone extends Activity {
    ImageButton btonImage;
    boolean isPressed = true;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_one);

        btonImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btonImage);
        btonImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound();toggleImage();
                }

        });
    }

    private void toggleImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btonImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }
}
```

this is the layout xml for image button

```
    <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btonImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:contentDescription="@null"
android:background="#080808"   
android:src="@drawable/image1" />
```

Comment: whats the current behavior of your code?

Comment: How exactly do you want to change the image?Change image color? size? pixels? use some filters? "Changing" is too general

Comment: i want to change the whole image to another and back to orignal image i am using an imagebutton e.g if image button is a mouse image when is clicked mice image comes and again mouse image comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the src to a drawable like this

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imgButtonBack"/>
```

And create a file named `imgButtonBack.xml` in drawable folder and set the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/presence_video_away"
       android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/presence_audio_busy"
      android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/presence_audio_busy" />
</selector>
```

Change the image as per your need

Comment: no doesn't solve the problem, image changes but the previous image doesn't come back.

Comment: put your mouse image in the last time where `presence_audio_busy` is present and put your mice image in android:state_pressed="true" drawable. Now the button would show mouse image and when pressed would show mice image and when u leave it, would how mouse again

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(R.layout.button_one);

This is your problem. You should set the entire layout and handle click event !